# exporting obj. file correctly from blender 2.9

Tags: obj

I am kindly asking you to assist me with fixing my obj. file. I made a bottle model in blender 2.9, exported it as an obj. file and sent it to the client. But when he opened the bottle in Dimension and placed a label over it, the half below part of the bottle is showing some problem and is not reflecting the graphic correctly (please see the uploaded picture). Can there be a problem with exporting obj. file from blender and how can I fix it? thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: It’s maybe because of inverted normals. Try selecting all and re-calculating them.

Comment: ZargulTheWizard thank you so much for your answer. I will try this.